# Android [root]: Correct way to restore/backup application data folder /data/user/0/app.id (doesn't work after cp -a)

Tags: android, linux, shell, file-permissions

A few days ago I realized that after restoring from a backup via TitaniumBackup, half of the programs did not start.

after 2 days, conducting tests on one of these programs, I came to this:

1. Do clean install of app (for example: `com.cootek.smartinputv5`)
2. Do first run (**success**)
3. Freeze this app (for preventing any changes)
4. Move original folder: `mv /data/user/0/com.cootek.smartinputv5/ /data/user/0/com.cootek.smartinputv5_BACK/`
5. Clone folder: `cp -a /data/user/0/com.cootek.smartinputv5_BACK/ /data/user/0/com.cootek.smartinputv5/`
6. Unfreeze app, run and get ERROR: **Not enought space**
7. Freeze again
8. `rm -rf /data/user/0/com.cootek.smartinputv5/`
9. `mv /data/user/0/com.cootek.smartinputv5_BACK/ /data/user/0/com.cootek.smartinputv5/`
10. Unfreeze app, run and **EVERYTHIG OK**.

Based on the results of the experiment, it is clear that the folders are not identical, if the application finds the difference between my copy and the original.

Ok, I tried to find difference (any `chmod` or `chown` etc) with that hack: `diff <(getfacl -R folder1) <(getfacl -R folder2)` but I got nothing! No difference!

Part of `getfacl` result:
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: I don’t know the exact reason, perhaps the databases are open in the system in this folder, perhaps binding by file descriptor, perhaps APEX is interfering with something, but I found a solution, **you just need to reboot**.

If you have same problem: **application dont work correctly after restoring data (manually or via TitaniumBackup)** you need to fix user permission on folder:

1. Find correct userId: `adb shell dumpsys package com.cootek.smartinputv5 | grep userId`. Example: `userId=10290` == `u0_a290`
2. Fix: `chown -R u0_a290:u0_a290 /data/data/com.cootek.smartinputv5`
3. Reboot